# Creating the N most accurate sparklines for M sets of data

Tags: algorithm

I recently constructed a simple name popularity tool (http://names.yafla.com) that allows users to select names and investigate their popularity over time and by state. This is just a fun project and has no commercial or professional value, but solved a curiosity itch.

One improvement I would like to add is the display of simple sparklines beside each name in the select list, showing the normalized national popularity trends since 1910.

Doing an image request for every single name -- where hypothetically I've preconstructed the spark lines for every possible variant -- would slow the interface too much and yield a lot of unnecessary traffic as users quickly scroll and filter past hundreds of names they aren't interested in. Building sprites with sparklines for sets of names is a possibility, but again with tens of thousands of names, in the end the user's cache would be burdened with a lot of unnecessary information.

My goal is absolutely tuned minimalism.

Which got me contemplating the interesting challenge of taking M sets of data (occurrences over time) and distilling that to the most proximal N representative sparklines. For this purpose they don't have to be exact, but should be a general match, and where I could tune N to yield a certain accuracy number.

Essentially a form of sparkline lossy compression.

I feel like this most certainly is a solved problem, but can't find or resolve the heuristics that would yield the algorithms that would shorten the path.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe seems to be cluster analysis - e.g. shoving that into Wikipedia will give you a starting point. Particular methods for cluster analysis include k-means and single linkage. A related topic is Latent Class Analysis.

If you do this, another option is to look at the clusters that come out, give them descriptive names, and then display the cluster names rather than inaccurate sparklines - or I guess you could draw not just a single line in the sparkline, but two or more lines showing the range of popularities seen within that cluster.